# How to fix "apt-get upgrade" errors?

Tags: upgrade, apt, kernel, dependencies, dkms

I get these errors when I try to upgrade the packages installed on my Ubuntu system:

```
m@m-desktop ~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up drbd8-source (2:8.3.7-1ubuntu2.3) ...
Removing old drbd8-8.3.7 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 8.3.7
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new drbd8-8.3.7 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 2.6.35-22-generic
Building for architecture i386
Building initial module for 2.6.35-22-generic

Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 2.6.35-22-generic (i386)
Consult the make.log in the build directory
/var/lib/dkms/drbd8/8.3.7/build/ for more information.
dpkg: error processing drbd8-source (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of drbd8-utils:
 drbd8-utils depends on drbd8-source; however:
  Package drbd8-source is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing drbd8-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 drbd8-source
 drbd8-utils
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
m@m-desktop ~ $
```

Comment: Are you running `sudo apt-get update` first? If not, is there any improvement when you do?

Comment: Please look for the file /var/lib/dkms/drbd8/8.3.7/build/make.log and add it to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --configure drbd8-source
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```