# How to fix apt-get upgrade (apt-get install -f) error?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates

Before I have read more sources like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152874/how-to-fix-apt-get-upgrade-errors) but didn't find an answer for my error, which is related with system updating package. We can see on top right here:

[image]

I have not so big experience in it. The error of updating like here:

[image]

proposes me to execute:

```
 apt-get -f install
```

also, I had been tried

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get -f install
apt-get install -f
```

but I have other error:

[image]

Please, maybe anybody has experience in that, thanks.

when I execute successfully:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall click
```

I still have the same error:
[image]

When I execute the command:

```
journalctl -xe
```

I have:
[image]
It seems like I need to install `click`.

Comment: run `sudo pip3 uninstall click`

Comment: Thanks, but the error is present still

Comment: What is the new error

Comment: Also, I found here a little bit about "click": https://askubuntu.com/questions/613512/how-to-get-removed-a-broken-package-in-this-case-click

Comment: Read the error message carefully: You seem to be trying to downgrade to an older version of python3-click-package. Why?

Comment: It shows me that the installation package is wrong and show that: "your installed packages have unmet dependencies "

Comment: @Arun: Should I do this for pip3 and for pip too ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using autoremove

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This is the command that cleans up dependencies after a package has been removed.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying but cannot get a good result yet.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the root cause is the lock file. Lock files are used to prevent two or more processes from using the same data. When apt or apt-commands are run, it creates lock files in a few places. When the previous apt command was not terminated properly, the lock files were not deleted and hence they prevent any new instances of apt/apt-get commands.

To fix the problem, all you need to do is to remove the lock files. You can do that easily using the commands below:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

After that, reconfigure the packages

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Now if you run the sudo apt update command, everything should be fine.